# Make a Table Containing Discriminant of a List

Tags: list-manipulation, table

I have a list

```
list = {x^3 - 3*(m - 10)*x^2 + 3*(3*m - 2)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(2*m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(3*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(6*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 8)*x^2 + 3*(m - 2)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 8)*x^2 + 3*(2*m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 3*(m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 3*(2*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 9*(m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 3*(5*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 6*(3*m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 6)*x^2 + 3*(4*m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 6)*x^2 + 6*(3*m + 2)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 5)*x^2 + 3*(m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 5)*x^2 + 6*(m - 1)*x};
```

With the first element of the list, I calculate Discriminant of derivative of it.
I tried

```
Discriminant[D[x^3 - 3*(m - 10)*x^2 + 3*(3*m - 2)*x, x], x]
```

I get

> 36 (102 - 23 m + m^2)

How to make a table in the form

```
{{pA, Discriminant[pA,x]}} where pA in list.
```

Comment: `{#, Discriminant[D[#, x], x]} & /@ list //
 Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {x^3 - 3*(m - 10)*x^2 + 3*(3*m - 2)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(2*m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(3*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 9)*x^2 + 3*(6*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 8)*x^2 + 3*(m - 2)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 8)*x^2 + 3*(2*m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 3*(m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 3*(2*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 9*(m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 3*(5*m + 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 7)*x^2 + 6*(3*m - 1)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 6)*x^2 + 3*(4*m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 6)*x^2 + 6*(3*m + 2)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 5)*x^2 + 3*(m - 3)*x, 
  x^3 - 3*(m - 5)*x^2 + 6*(m - 1)*x};

fun[dt_] := {dt, Discriminant[D[dt, x], x]}

fun /@ list // TableForm
```

[image]

**Addendum**

To get the derivatives at a certain point:

```
der[dt_, p_] := D[dt, x] /. {x :> p}

res = der[#, 2] & /@ list
```

{12 - 12 (-10 + m) + 3 (-2 + 3 m), 12 - 12 (-9 + m) + 3 (-3 + m),
12 - 12 (-9 + m) + 3 (-3 + 2 m), 12 - 12 (-9 + m) + 3 (1 + 3 m),
12 - 12 (-9 + m) + 3 (1 + 6 m), 12 - 12 (-8 + m) + 3 (-2 + m),
12 - 12 (-8 + m) + 3 (-1 + 2 m), 12 - 12 (-7 + m) + 3 (-1 + m),
12 - 12 (-7 + m) + 3 (1 + 2 m), 12 - 12 (-7 + m) + 9 (-1 + m),
12 - 12 (-7 + m) + 3 (1 + 5 m), 12 - 12 (-7 + m) + 6 (-1 + 3 m),
12 - 12 (-6 + m) + 3 (-3 + 4 m), 12 - 12 (-6 + m) + 6 (2 + 3 m),
12 - 12 (-5 + m) + 3 (-3 + m), 12 - 12 (-5 + m) + 6 (-1 + m)}

```
res /. m :> 12
```

{90, 3, 39, 87, 195, -6, 33, -15, 27, 51, 135, 162, 75, 168, -45, -6}

The parameter `p` doesn't need to be numeric. You can also do:

```
der[list[[1]], w]
```

3 (-2 + 3 m) - 6 (-10 + m) w + 3 w^2

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I insert derivative of all element at the point `x = 2`?